# Google maps marker size with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I am currently working on a google-maps project using google-maps-react and I have come across a problem. I am using props to get the values of my marker (lat, lng, marker icon) however I am having trouble changing the size of the marker. I am left with an enormous marker and not able to change this. I have tries to pass the size as a prop but without success.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is my code:

MAPS.JS

```
render() {
    /*--- initial code that i passed into props*/
     /*var icon = {
     url: "https://loc8tor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/stencil.png", // url
    scaledSize: new this.props.google.maps.Size(90, 42), // scaled size
    */
     }
 return (
      <div className="map-container">
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          className={"map"}
          zoom={4}
          initialCenter={this.props.center}
        >
          {this.props.places.map((place, i) => {
              //pass an array of markers as a child to the GoogleMap component and map over them
            return (
              <Marker
                onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                key={place.id}
                place_={place}
                position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng }}
                icon={place.url}
                //Size={place.scaledSize} : Not working
              />
            );
          })}
          <InfoWindowEx
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          >
            <div>
              <h3>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h3>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.showDetails.bind(this, this.state.selectedPlace)}
              >

                Show details
              </button>
            </div>
          </InfoWindowEx>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
```

INDEX.JS

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Map from "./Map";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Hello",
    title: "Sydney",
    lat: -33.847927,
    lng: 150.6517938,
    id: 1,
    color: "blue",
    url: "https://loc8tor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/stencil.png",
    // scaledSize: Size(90, 42), // scaled size - Not working//
     },
  {
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be complete

Answer (score 2):

The `scaledSize` parameter must be added to your marker's `icon` property along with the `url` parameter as per the library's [docs](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react) and Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons).

So if you have this object containing both parameters:

```
var icon = {
  url: "https://loc8tor.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/stencil.png",
  scaledSize: new this.props.google.maps.Size(90, 42)
};
```

Pass them both to your marker's `icon` property together as an object as follows:

```
<Marker
  onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
  key={place.id}
  place_={place}
  position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng }}
  icon={icon}
/>
```

I have tested your code with the above changes and your blue marker displays correctly at the specified size. So hope this helps you!

Comment: in react I had to do ```icon={{ url: iconUrl, scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(90, 42) }}```

Comment: thank you @smooth_smoothie the `new` was important to me as well ....